# Heroku API not able to access cookies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cookies

I have hosted a JWT auth API on heroku. While accessing the API using axios from my front-end React app, I notice that the protected routes can never be fetched since they are dependent on res.cookies which are never set. While testing the API out on postman, it sets the cookies and everything works fine. Can you help me finding where I am going wrong and how I can overcome this.

Sample cookie that is supposed to be set(working fine with postman)
[image: Using post route on postman, sets the aforementioned cookie]

This cookie is needed, because when I GET /user, with the following code:

```
exports.checkUser = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    let currentUser;
    if (req.cookies.jwt) {
        const token = req.cookies.jwt;
        const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
    } else {
        currentUser = null;
    }

    res.status(200).send({ currentUser });
});
```

currentUser should be populated as follows

[image: currentUser field is populated.]

When I access this API using my react frontend: this being my useAuth hook

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { UserContext } from "./userContext";

export default function useAuth() {
    let history = useHistory();
    const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const setUserContext = async () => {
        return await axios
            .get("<my api link>/user")
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setUser(res.data.currentUser);
                history.push("/home");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                setError(err);
            });
    };

    const registerUser = async (data) => {
        const { username, email, password, passwordConfirm, name } = data;
        return axios
            .post("<My api link>/auth/post", {
                username,
                email,
                password,
                passwordConfirm,
                name,
            })
            .then(async (res) => {
                console.log(res);
                await setUserContext();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                return setError(err);
            });
    };
```

res.data.currentUser is ALWAYS null. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The concept of JWT is that the **handling of the token is handed over to the client.**

Hence, the frontend is supposed to store/save the JWT Token it receives in cookies or `localstorage` and is supposed to send them via `headers` in requests where you want to access such protected routes.

Hence it's the frontend duty and that's why Postman handles it automatically for you.

You can use [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) to save and retrieve this JWT token in the frontend whenever required and you will have to reform your `axios` request.

In your specific case, you can do the following for GET request:

```js
axios.get('URL', {
  withCredentials: true
});
```

But I would strongly recommend amending your backend to extract JWT tokens from `headers` instead of cookies, which would make your request, something similar to:

```js
let JWTToken = 'xxyyzz'; // Get this from cookie or localstorage, hardcoded for demonstration.
 axios
    .get("URL", { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${JWTToken}`} })
    .then(res => {
       this.profile = res.data;
       console.log('Fetched Data is', res.data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

*Do not forget to enable CORS on your backend!*